# How to apply existing facial blend shapes to beard

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

Does anyone know how I could attach a beard to a face/head so it's affected by morph targets (face expressions) of the character? I've tried to combine vertices of the beard with the face thinking like that i could get the beard to move too.. But as soon as I combined a few, all went haywire.. I've thought of locking the vertices too of the beard with the face too but it didn't seem to work.. So question is how to get the existing blend shapes to work with the beard?? Any help is really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to be specific without knowing the detail, but I'd try creating shape keys for the beard to match the shape-keyed movements of the face then, when you're finally setting up controls, link them so you run face and beard drivers simultaneously. Obviously this won't help a lot if you're after a big bushy beard that has a lot of follow-through (that'll mean a bit of extra tweaking).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying a surface deform modifier on the beard, targeting the face.

Depending on the beard, it might be good to sandwich in an extra (non-rendering) surface deformer there as well-- so that you can limit the surface that's used to deform the beard.  Copy the face surface, delete irrelevant bits, surface deform copy from face, then surface deform beard from copy.

How well anything works is going to depend on the beard in question.  If you need to turn these into shapekeys, you can do that by pinning the face's shapekey, then saving the modifier as a new shapekey for the beard, rinse and repeat.